# Spring Boot - Using import.sql in production?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am building a RESTful API using Spring Data REST with Spring boot. There are some data (eg. a list of countries) I would like to insert into the database when it is created so I am using `import.sql` to do this. But in the spring boot [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) it is mentioned that `import.sql` is not good for production. To quote:

> In addition, a file named import.sql in the root of the classpath will be executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch (that is if the ddl-auto property is set to create or create-drop). This can be useful for demos and for testing if you are careful, but probably not something you want to be on the classpath in production. It is a Hibernate feature (nothing to do with Spring).

So my question is why is it bad to have import.sql in production and what would be a better alternative?

**Note**: I am only going to use `import.sql` the first time the application is deployed to production after that I will turn off `hibernate-ddl`. Any further changes to the schema will be made using Flyway.

Comment: do you want to insert data into ur tables, or create schema?

Comment: I want to insert the data into tables

Comment: i don't know why it is not a good option, but you can always use `jackson`. and i can make an answer if you wish. but did you try `.sql` and it leads to a specific problem?

Comment: Because this is mainly meant to create the schema, and you really don't want to create the schema from scratch every time the application is restarted or redeployed. Moreover, it isn't designed to support multiple servers starting in parallel and all targetting the same database. Use the appropriate tools to do that: FlywayDB or Liquibase: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool. Hibernate schema creation support is used for rapid prototyping while developing, not for production.

Comment: @Salman  Jackson is a JSON mapping library. Nothing to do with databases.

Comment: @JBNizet i can use it to pre-populate data into the database. Why not?

Comment: @JBNizet I actually meant using import.sql the first time the application is deployed to production. After that I am going to turn off hibernate-ddl

Comment: Also I am going to use flyway to do any future changes to schema

Comment: @JBNizet You just said *Jackson has nothing to do with databases.* Meanwhile, i said, i can populate data into the database using `jackson`.

Comment: @DeltaCharlie why not use Flyway from the start. Imagine a new developer comes in after the 10th production deployment, and must install the app on his/her workstation. How Will the schema be created then: hibernate-ddl will be turned off, and the schema is empty, so you can't create the schema anymore.

Comment: @JBNizet I have created different `application.properties` profiles for development and production. So when a new developer comes he can just switch to development profile without having to modify the production profile.